# Any languages beside English where one goes"back and forth" rather than "forth and back"?

Tags: english, list-of-languages, idiomaticity, set-phrases

Are there languages beside English in which one goes "back and forth" rather than, as is logical, "forth and back"?  One typically goes "forth and back" or similarly in French, German, Spanish. Italian, Romanian, Hebrew to describe an oscillatory type of movement.

Notably, we do jump "up and down" rather than "down and up".

Thank you!

Comment: If “hither and thither” counts, Ukrainian uses both, actually both “hither and thither” and «thither and hither» are used.

Comment: Not exactly the same, @YellowSky reminds me that modern spoken German tends to use "her-" (or just "r-") and "hin-" without much logic.  "Hineinkommen" ("Come thither", i.e. away from the speaker), "Rausgehen" ("Go hither", i.e. to the speaker).  My Sprachgefühl says that most dialects (including the standard one) either overuse one or the other.

Comment: The reason that we go *back and forth* has to do with the sounds of the individual words in the binomial/freeze.

Comment: How on earth is "forward and back" more logical than "back and forth"? And English also has it the other way around with "to and fro."

Comment: @cmw In the same way that deixis tends to start conceptually at the speaker’s vision and move outwards, so do motion and direction: coming (towards us) before going (away from us), up (where our vision starts, at the eyes) before down (where it doesn’t, at the feet), forward (what we see) before backward (what we can’t see), etc. Where neither option is obviously nearer the eye, there’s more cross-linguistic variation: left/right, in/out, across/across, deasil/widdershins, etc. So yes, there is some logic to it, and English _back and forth_ does go against the grain here.

Comment: @Araucaria-him I’m not really convinced that that’s true. Or at least, it doesn’t hold for the longer _backward(s)_ and _forward(s)_, where [Ngrams say](https://bit.ly/3JhmTKw) that the order of preference is _backwards and forwards_ → _forward and backward_ → _backward and forward_ → _forwards and backwards_. That is, with _-s_, B-F is more common; without _-s_, F-B is more common. For the shorter version, _front and back_ is virtually nonexistent, _back and forth_ being more than 100 times more common.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, it's not "English" per se, since English *also* has "to and fro." I don't agree though that "logic" is the right word for what is typically done. It's too ad hoc. I could easily say that "back and forth" is "logical" because it is easier to say rapidly compared to "forth and back."

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Or one could bring in time. You have to start somewhere first before going forward. Etc. Any of those types of appeals are ad hoc and starts to sound a bit like hyper-proscriptivism, even if that's not the intent.

Comment: @cmw I never said it was English per se. I said it was English _back and forth_; ‘to and fro’ doesn’t enter the picture. Whether it’s “easier to say rapidly” depends entirely on the individual words and is cross-linguistically irrelevant. My point was that these pairs _across languages_ tend to follow that order. _Back and forth_ goes against the grain and has it ‘backwards’, unlike the equivalent phrases in German, French, Greek, Mandarin, Irish, etc., while _to and fro_ follows the logic. Amharic has it ‘backwards’ too, if Google Translate is to be believed.

Comment: @cmw How on earth can a description of which order languages tend to use when pairing deictics and similar expressions be any kind of proscriptive?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I said calling it "logical" is proscriptive.

Comment: @cmw Fair enough, a better word than ‘logical’ could have been used in the question – though I’ll note that I didn’t call it logical either, I only said that there is a certain logic that underpins it (whether that logic in actuality is particularly logical or not).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yeah, I'm in particular taking exception with OP's phrase, "as is logical."

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What your data backs up is that binomials/freezes have syntactic and lexical components. There is a binomial involving the prepositions *backwards* and *forwards* as shown by the Google data. However, there is no binomial corresponding to either the adjectives *forward* or *backward* or their homonymous prepositions. The phonetic considerations which affect the order of binomials do not apply to random conjoined XPs, in other words conjuncts that aren't binomials.